# Права на удаление комментариев. передать

Tags: вконтакте

подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

я встроил на сайт виджет комментариев от вконтакте. я могу удалять любые комментарии из ленты(свои и чужие). хотелось бы передать такие же права другому пользователю сети вконтакте(даже если придётся мне потерять возможность удалять комментарии)

Comment: ну а что говорит API контакта по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не по программированию, но отвечу, т.к. совсем недавно с этим столкнулся.

Шаг 1. Клик по надписи "администрирование":
[image: скриншот 1]

Шаг 2. Справа — «Назначить администраторов»:
[image: скриншот 2]

Это перебросит в управление Приложением, id которого использует виджет. Там можно добавить других администраторов, которые смогут удалять комменты. Необязательно при этом самому лишаться каких-то прав.

Answer (score 0):

Авторизуйтесь для начала под собой, далее перейдите к форме комментариев на вашем сайте, и кликните на ссылку администрирование, там можно удалять и добавлять доп. админов

[image]

[image]